# Swing JTree - How to use the Netbeans GUI to make the tree single selection?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtree

I'm using Netbeans GUI interface for creating the Swing components.

I've added a JTree to the panel. It appears to be multi-select by default.

Anybody know how in Netbeans I change this to a single-select? I'm not seeing anything exposed in the properties.

Full Answer:
Right after "initComponents()" in the constructor, I added the following:

```
TreeSelectionModel model = jTreeInput.getSelectionModel();
model.setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
```

"jTreeInput" is the name of my jTree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do it in netbeans, but you could also write a couple of lines of code:

```
TreeSelectionModel model = yourJTree.getSelectionModel();
model.setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option is to set it in code:

```
myJTree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode
                       (TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
```

In Netbeans, `JTree` has a `selectionModel` property for this purpose, but requires you to create a custom class derived from `TreeSelectionModel` with the selection mode set to `SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION`.